# Determinant of this linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations, determinant

Let $T:V\to V, T(A)=BAB^*$, where $V$ is the vector space of all $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ and $B$ is some fixed complex matrix.

I need to show $\det T=\lvert \det B \rvert^{2n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's sometimes a bit easier to begin more generally, and only pick bases and get matrix representations at a later stage.

Let $U$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $V$ be the space of linear transformations $U\to U$. Let $\beta$ be a fixed element of $V$, and define $T: V\to V$ by $\alpha\mapsto \beta\alpha\beta^{*}$. We want to find $\det T$.

First we do the case where $\beta$ is diagonalisable, choosing a basis of $U$ consisting of eigenvectors of $\beta$,  $u_1,\dots, u_n$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$. For a basis of $V$ we choose the usual $\epsilon_{ij}$ defined by $\epsilon_{ij}u_r=\delta_{jr}u_i$.

Now the $\epsilon_{ij}$ form a basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors: as $\beta=\sum \lambda_i \epsilon_{ii}$ it takes but a moment to calculate that $T(\epsilon_{ij})=\lambda_i\bar{\lambda}_j \epsilon_{ij}$.

It is easy to calculate the determinant of a diagonal matrix, and so we have $\det T=|\det\beta|^{2n}$.

In the usual way with such identities we can now appeal to the density of the diagonalisable transformations to get the result for all transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $\mathbb{C}$ as $F$. You can start by considering the linear transformation$$L_B :\ F^{n\times n}\to\ F^{n\times n}$$
$$A\ \mapsto BA$$Rewrite $A$ as column vectors $(A_1,A_2,...,A_n)$, then the transformation is $(A_1,A_2,...,A_n)\ \mapsto (BA_1,BA_2,...,BA_n)$. Define  $$T_B:F^{n\times 1}\to\ F^{n\times 1}$$ $$X \mapsto BX$$Then $det(T_B)=det(B)$.Notice that $F^{n\times n}=F^n \times F^n \times ...\times F^n$.Define$$T^k_B:F^n \times F^n \times ...\times F^n \to F^n \times F^n \times ...\times F^n$$
$$(A_1,A_2,...,A_n)\mapsto (A_1,A_2,...,BA_k,...,A_n)$$Then $det(T^k_B)=det(T_B)=det(B)$. Since $L_B=T^1_B \circ T^2_B \circ...\circ T^n_B$, $det(L_B)=det(T^1_B)\cdot det(T^2_B) ...\cdot det(T^n_B)=det(B)^n$. And $det(T)=det(L_B)det(R_{B^*})=\vert det(B) \vert^{2n} $.

Comment: @peterag Thanks. I'll edit my answer.